# Go Protobuf Coder/Encoder Errors

Tags: go, kubernetes, protocol-buffers

I am trying to create a `.proto` file for a Kubernetes custom resource and hence I need to include the `ObjectMeta` in my file. I am doing it like this:

```
syntax = "proto2";
package spec;

import "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/api/unversioned/generated.proto";
import "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/api/v1/generated.proto";

message APIKeyList {
  optional string kind = 1;
  optional string apiVersion = 2;
  optional k8s.io.kubernetes.pkg.api.unversioned.ListMeta metadata = 3;
  repeated APIKey items = 4;
}
```

Using `protoc`, it successfully creates my `*.pb.go` file however when I run my test suite, I receive the following error:

```
proto: no coders for unversioned.Time
proto: no encoder for CreationTimestamp unversioned.Time [GetProperties]
proto: tag has too few fields: "-"
proto: no coders for time.Time
proto: no encoder for Time time.Time [GetProperties]
proto: no slice oenc for *reflect.rtype = []*reflect.rtype
proto: no encoder for OwnerReferences []v1.OwnerReference [GetProperties]
```

Now I am not using any time fields and so I assume is has something to do with the imported proto files.

Comment: Have you tried to compile in proto3 instead of proto2?

Comment: @TrevorVarwig yes and received the same result. The errors seem to be occurring when type assertion is performed on the type.